# Issue with jenkins security

Tags: jenkins

I installed a fresh copy of jenkins 1.609 and configured one job (I had multiple instances of previous jenkins versions earlier). I wanted to protect this instance, in particular protect the jobs and everything, since it runs on the internet.

When I activate security, and check jenkins-own user database checkbox as well as logged-in users can do everything checkbox and save it, it seems to have no effect, as anonymous user is still able to access the job and the workspace of the job.

When I active use-matrix-based security and give my user admin (actually all) rights, the job isn't visible anymore, but I lose all privileges and I see

```
<username> is missing the Overall/Administer permission
```

immediately. After that I have no access to administration overview anymore.

So question from my side, what should I choose if I want the anonymous user to see a blank page, and logged in user to do everything.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is choose the "Matrix-based security" option with the configuration below:

[image]

Then, you just have to set the relevant permissions to authenticated users.

Anonymous users will not be able to access your Jenkins server :)

Comment: I did exactly that, but it locks me out of the server... I can access the jobs, but I can't access any administration functions anymore.

Comment: I did a test on my Jenkins environment with the above options and it worked well. When I'm not logged in, I'm not able to access the server, I'm redirected on the login page. Once I'm logged in, I can see everything (because I've checked the admin option in the permissions table). Did you create the line for the authenticated users?

Comment: May I ask which choice of security model is recommanded? Matrix-based security or Realm/Roles? Is it possible to be in a wrong mixed state because of some misunderstood?

Comment: Is there another URL than https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json where the plugins would be more validated (something equivalent to a debian stable)? Very offen, plugins break what is working.

Comment: @Sandburg We are using the "Role-Based Strategy" and it's working fine.
You just have to install this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin

Comment: Regarding the update center, the link you sent is the stable one. If you want to install some experimental plugins, you can use this link: https://updates.jenkins.io/experimental/update-center.json.
The only way to stop breaking your Jenkins instance is to validate the plugin's upgrade on a staging environment.

Comment: @bruno-lavit 1: Role-Based is what we are using too. But it's really crappy by us. Are there some good practices or full demo? - 2: Updates On the contrary, the stable one is not stable enough. 3 plugins / month have too heavy requirements: reconfigure or incompatibilities.

Comment: I think to write a new question on this theme. We are planing to scale up our Jenkins tools... security + settings of views become a problem more than ever. So I need to know what is the best approach in 2019!